# Need help for a picture please (II)

Tags: pspicture

I know that I should learn TikZ... I'd need help for this very simple picture (there are two colors red and blue, it's an illustration for an argument, the case depicted is n=3).

[image]

I would be very grateful if someone could give me the code. Otherwise I will do something with xfig in black and white. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the point (1/n,1-1/n) be programmable? Meaning that you can give it different values of `n` and the image will be changed

Comment: @Jes No. The case depicted is n=3.

Comment: So you want it in ps or Ti*k*Z would fit? Did you try something? This is a rather dull graphic to make, actually.

Comment: By saying it's a dull graphic, I said 'why don't you try a bit?' You didn't need to jump on it like this. I posted a different answer to let you see what's possible when using node along a path, which I prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :) As you said that you wanted to learn tikz, I have more or less commented everything so you have a reference. If you have questions about a part of the code, feel free to ask! This is the result:

[image]

And the code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %- Draw blue part
        \begin{scope}[color = blue]
            \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1.25,0); % X - axis
            \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1.25); % Y - axis
            \draw[] (1,0) -- (1,1);
            \draw[] (0,1) -- (1,1);
            \node [below,left] () at (0,0) { \tiny (0,0)};
            \node [above,right] () at (1,1) { \tiny (1,1)};
        \end{scope}
        
        %- Draw red part
        \begin{scope}[color = red]
            \node[below] (xPoint) at (1/3,0){\tiny $\frac{1}{n}$}; % Label on x axis
            \node[left] (yPoint) at (0,2/3){\tiny 1-$\frac{1}{n}$}; % Label on y axis
            \draw[dashed] (xPoint) -- (1/3,2/3); % Line between x axis and (1/3,2/3)
            \draw[dashed] (yPoint) -- (1/3,2/3); % Line between y axis and (1/3,2/3)
            \fill (0,0) circle (1pt); % Red circle at (0,0)
            \fill (1/3,2/3) circle (1pt); 
            \fill (1,1) circle (1pt); 
            \draw (0,0) -- (1/3,2/3) -- (1,1) node[midway,below] (){\tiny $\varphi_n$};
            % In the draw command above, I have created the text by writing a node in the middle of the last segment
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the offer but no need! As SebGlav said, its a quite easy to do graph on tikz once you have a little experience with it. I did it because I was really confused with tikz when I started, and having a reference is usually easier that doing something from scratch :)

Answer (score 4):

A shorter answer using nodes on the fly. And the possibility of changing the value of *n*.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \def\n{3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[cyan,scale=4,pn/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=2pt,fill=red}]
        \draw[->] (-.1,0) -- (1.2,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-.1) -- (0,1.2);
        \draw[densely dashed] (0,1) -| (1,0);
        \draw[red] (0,0) node[pn] {}  node[cyan,below left] {$(0\,,0)$} -- (1/\n,1-1/\n) node[pn] {} -- (1,1) node[midway,below] {$\varphi_n$} node[pn] {} node[cyan,above right] {$(1\,,1)$};
        \draw[red,densely dotted] (0,1-1/\n) node[left] {$1-\dfrac{1}{n}$} -| (1/\n,0) node[below] {$\dfrac{1}{n}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: very simple graph]

Comment: Thanks, I have 2 TikZ programs to read now :-).

Comment: Nice answer! Definitely less cluttered than mine. What does `node[pn]` do?

Comment: `pn` doesn't mean anything, it's just a style I definined to draw the red circles. Here, it's defined into the `tikzpicture`declaration, but you can achieve the same thing by writing `\tikzset{pn/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, ...}}`

Comment: Oops I did not read the tikz options before asking. Sorry and thanks for the clarification. As I said before, very clever and short code :D